# How do I apply a configuration to a suite of property-based tests?

Tags: f#, xunit, fscheck

How do I apply a configuration to a suite of property-based tests?

**I tried the following:**

```
let config = { Config.Quick with MaxTest = 10000
                                 QuietOnSuccess = true }

[<Property(Config=config)>] // Doesn't work because "Config" is a private member
let ``my property-based test`` () =
   ...
```

However, the `Config` member is set to private and will not compile.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to set `MaxTest` to `10000`, use the `MaxTest` property:

```
[<Property(MaxTest = 10000, QuietOnSuccess = true)>]
let ``my property-based test`` () =
   // ...
```

If you feel that this violates the DRY principle to have to type that for every property, you can create a derived attribute:

```
type MyPropertyAttribute() =
    inherit PropertyAttribute(
        MaxTest = 10000,
        QuietOnSuccess = true)
```

and then use that attribute on your properties instead:

```
[<MyProperty>]
let ``my property-based test`` () =
   // ...
```